# Using Angular Material Design ng-model date format works but firebug throws error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, material-design

I am trying to format a date time and it works but, firebug throws an error

This is my code.

```
<md-input-container>
<input ng-model="item.myDate| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" disabled=""/>
</md-input-container>
```

So for instance if I put this: 2016-01-04T14:37:35.029

I do get this: 2016-01-04

but here is firebugs error:

Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'item.myDate| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'' is non-assignable. Element: 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ngModel/nonassign?p0=item.myDate ....

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Just FYI- I do not want to use ng-value as I am going to loose the page format.
or this  <input value="{{item.myDate| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" disabled=""/>

Answer (score 1):

```
item.myDate = $filter('date')(item.myDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

ng-model can't use date filter format. you can try above code in your js file.

Comment: If you explain how can i assign this to above question, 'll be appreciable. Thanks in advance.